# Can I do research based on the statistics on votes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

Is it possible to do research or gather information about the voting behavior of members with high and low reputation points? Or if any research has been carried about it?

From voting behavior, in its simplest definitions, I mean upvotes or downvotes they cast to a question (it can include more parameters though). **It's more about statistics and not necessarily interpretation.**

I give you an example about the statistics I mean. Take this question for example; let's assume it has N upvotes and M downvotes. Take an arbitrary level, L, (for example 1,000), and then you may find 90% of people above L (1,000) gave a downvote to the question. It indicates a level of consistency or co-relation between downvotes and reputation points in this interval (**by consistency I mean similar behavior**). But if it was 50% it indicates inconsistency. (50% down, 50% up).

In this case then you could change the Level (for example 2,000) and you'll find 90% of members with above 2,000 downvoted this question. You could conclude that this is a more consistent interval. For whatever reason, I know you should have the same number of people for the categories, but it's just an example. I thought there were such trends that could be found.

An example of the application of such results: to cast a downvote on a question one needs, at least, 125 reputation points. Some may argue it must be lower or higher (how have you really reached that number?). We might find an interval in which the voting is more consistent.

Comment: what is the definition of a "high" and "low" rep member?

Comment: What's your definition of voting behavior? Merely using the votes? Using them properly? If so, what's your definition of using them properly?

Comment: I edited the question to answer your questions. simply up or down votes.

Comment: *the reason they have behind it* this is unknowable

Comment: @Ahmad Voting is anonymous ...

Comment: @Plutonix right soon I removed that part, I edited again to convey my meaning, I mean just statistics and percentages...

Comment: What exactly is your goal with this?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I gave an example and application in the question. consistent voting is better than inconsistent. for example its the reason why new members have less privileges. I like to see is it any reps we can call above that more consitent and familiared with the system or not.

Comment: *an interval in which the voting is more consistent* this assumes the voting is somehow *INconsistent*.  The bulk the votes would likely come from frequent or TopUsers and not necessarily be related to rep.  Since it is pretty easy to get to 2k rep, I suspect those in the 500-2k range might be quite active.

Comment: @Ahmad Someone who downvotes every question they see is consistently downvoting. Their behavior is consistent so it is good, right?

Comment: @Ahmad But to judge consistency, we would have to be able to judge whether a vote is correct or not. Which is not possible - it's always a subjective decision. SO's voting system - well, any voting system really - is basically just the sum of the subjective decisions of all its voters

Comment: @Pekka웃 I asked more for statistics, the interpretation could be any.

Comment: you can see the overall pattern for any user by [looking at their profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).  To draw some irrational conclusions about whatever troubles you, run a SEDE query

Comment: You still haven't specified *what* statistics you want. What specific pieces of information do you want, for what reputation level increments? "Consistency" is not a measurable piece of data.

Comment: @Louis I mean consistent in a category of members. I assumed the voting behavior of more informd and familiared members is more consistent than new members. it could be about reputations, if we just research statistics.

Comment: You can research the tags [voting] and [data-explorer] at [se]. Beside SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer), there's also public available data at the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Ahmad But that's the thing we keep telling you: unless you are going to take completely external criteria for deciding "consistency", there's no way to measure "consistency". If one day I downvote a question *only* because it is full of typos because I hold that this many typos *mandates* that I downvote, but the next day there's a question that has as many typos and I upvote it, I'm being inconsistent in how I apply my criteria but how are you going to *detect that*?

Comment: @Louis I added an example to question to clarify my meaning, I don't mean consistent behavior of one individual, I mean consistent or similar behavior by a group of members.

Comment: @Ahmad Even at the group level, you have to start with something you *can* measure. The example you added is helpful in clarifying what *you* mean by consistency. After posting my previous comment, I ran through a few possible ideas of what consistency *could* mean, even at the group level, and none of my ideas were what you finally added to your question.

Comment: @Louis I am not native and maybe don't select right words. Anyway that was my purpose.

Comment: @Louis, I also emphasized I mean in its simplest way, number of down or up votes. votes are measurable.

Comment: @Ahmad Looking at your example closely, there is still a problem. What about those who say "meh" and don't vote because the question is neither worthy of an upvote nor worthy of a downvote? I do not think there is any way to know how many read the question but did not vote. (You can get a number of views but it won't be broken down by reputation and even then, a single individual could raise the count more than once.)

Comment: rep level is a pretty arbitrary partition; when it was at 500 (rev 1) it was almost 50-50 memberwise; at 125 (rev 5) and 1000 (this revision) much less so.  Rep is meaningless though when you consider voters are more likely related to activity level.  Just because someone has "high" rep doesnt have any bearing on voting sense, voting pattern(s) or anything else.  Again, visit SEDE to find out some of what you are after.

Comment: @Plutonix we may can't judge there is not such things before we research, I just liked to know any research has been carried or not. the result could say there is no meaningful relation. thanks I will look at it.

Comment: @Louis the method to find which members visited a question is feasible. (however its hard to say they read it, but the time on visiting could help). Anyway, you want to say really there is no relation? there is some good assumption behind it. For example for a group of people who knows the rules better they have similar votes. Moderators for example soon can find the faults of a question and down-vote it, you say no?

Comment: No, there is no correlation between the two; rep and voting are different things.  Jon Skeet has 700K rep because he has given good answers over a long period of time.  It says *nothing* about his voting sense or pattern, but you assume up front there is.  The group you should actually be concerned with are what we might call "tag captains": those who are very active in a particular tag.  *They* are more likely to DV bad and even borderline questions as part of keeping the tag "clean" and partly (probably) out of frustration at the zillions of crap questions asked every hour.

Comment: @Plutonix thanks my assumption about similarity among high reputed and low reputed could be wrong. Maybe there are some other measures to divide members better. Anyway thanks.

Comment: I edited the question, considering the question and the accepted answer, its obvious what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such statistics and researches could be carried by using [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), there's also public available data at the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com), However its not possible to query the user id of voters. Votes (Up and Down) are anonymous and unfortunately your research couldn't be done by using SEDE.